# what is a cofunction expression equal to csc(π/7 )?

Tags: trigonometry

Use a cofunction to write an expression equal to  $$csc(\frac{\pi}{7} )$$. what is a cofunction equal to $$csc(\frac{\pi}{7} )$$?

Comment: If by cofunction you mean cosine function, then use the identity:$$\csc(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\theta)}}$$

Comment: @Mufasa It's true if and only if $\theta\in(\pi k,\pi k+\pi)$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the identity $\csc x = \sec\left({\pi \over 2} - x\right).$ So $$\begin{align}\csc\left({\pi \over 7}\right) &= \sec\left({\pi \over 2} - {\pi \over 7}\right)\\ &= \sec\left({7\pi - 2\pi \over 14}\right) \\ &= \sec\left({5 \over 14} \pi\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: The identity is true if and only if $x\neq \pi k$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Definitely, which in this case it isn't. :D

Comment: Blame http://www.mathwords.com/c/cofunction_identities.htm for their poor documentation of domains.